# com.alamofireJsonToObjects.error code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, swift4

I have run into this problem and I cant seem to find any reasonable explanation nor solution.

Just recently I have migrated application from swift 2.3 to swift 3 and then to swift 4.

Today I have noticed that an API call that is returning HTTP status code 200 is interpreted as error in my iOS application. Example of API call:

```
self.clientApi.post(path: path,
                    parameters: params as [String : AnyObject]?,
                    encoding: Alamofire.URLEncoding(), 
                    headers: nil,
                    success: { (result: ResultType) in
                        onSuccess()
                    }, failure: { (error, statusCode) in
                        onError(error, statusCode)
                    })
```

Using fiddler I can see that my API is returning status code 200 after this call, but onError() method is called and so on my application is thinking that request failed.

Error information that I have:

```
Type: NSError?
domain: "com.alamofirejsontoobjects.error
code: 1
```

What is not getting through my head is that I don't even use JSONEncoding here, I use URLEncoding because it is call to OAuth endpoint.

Please help.

Comment: Update Alamofire pod/framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling all pods it has worked like a charm.

Thank you @Nitish